# OnDeviceReady concealing functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appmobi

Sorry this is quite a but of code it is all relevant since I have no idea what the problem is, also the code may be too hard to read I tend to write first clean up later but hopefully someone will know what is happening. The problem is that I cannot call any of the functions from a button in html as they come out "undefined". I think it may be that they are somehow wrapped in the onDeviceReady() function so that they arent actually defined just an instance of them that disappears. But I cannot fix it no matter what I try.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Geolocation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">         </script>
    <link href="retrieveCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/appmobi.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function onDeviceReady() 
        {

            AppMobi.device.hideSplashScreen();
        }
        document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 var beachMarker;
var locations = new Array();


var _map = null;
var _seconds = 2;
var _llbounds = null;



function drawMap()
{

    var url =  "http://localhost/getloc.php";   
    var data;
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
    var rendererOptions = 
    {
        draggable: true
    };
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom:14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        zoomControl:false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
    };
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    $.get(url, data, function (data) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {

            locations[i] = data[i];
        }
    },  'json')
    .done(function() {
        setMarkers();
    });

    _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(_map);

}


var currentLatitude;
var currentLongitude;
var options = {
                 timeout: 1000,
                 maximumAge: 2000,
                 enableHighAccuracy: true
              };
var suc = function(p)
{
    if( _map == null ) 
    {
        currentLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
        currentLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
        drawMap();
    }

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
            var status = AppMobi.cache.getCookie("statusCookie");
            var name = AppMobi.cache.getCookie("usernameCookie");
            var location = p.coords.latitude + ", " + p.coords.longitude;
            var url = "http://localhost/pickmeup.php";
            var data = 'name=' +name+'&location='+location+'&status='+status;
                    $.post(url, data, function (data) 
                    {


                    });

            var posting = $.post( url, { 
                       name: name, 
                       location: location, 
                       status: status
                   });

            if (status == "green")
            {   
                curIcon = "greenicon.png";
            }
            else if (status == "yellow")
            {
                curIcon = "yellowicon.png";
            }
            else if (status == "red")
            {
                curIcon = "redicon.png";
            }

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'images/marker.png',
                new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(16,32)
            );
            if (beachMarker != null)
            {
                beachMarker.setMap(null);
            }
            beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: _map,
            icon: curIcon
            });
};

var fail = function()
{
    console.log("Geolocation failed. \nPlease enable GPS in Settings.",1);
};



//AppMobi is ready to roll
function onDeviceReady()
{
    try
    {
        if (AppMobi.device.platform.indexOf("Android")!=-1)
        {
            AppMobi.display.useViewport(480,480);
            document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width="480px";
        }
        else if (AppMobi.device.platform.indexOf("iOS")!=-1)
        {
            if (AppMobi.device.model.indexOf("iPhone")!=-1 || AppMobi.device.model.indexOf("iPod")!=-1)
            {
                AppMobi.display.useViewport(320,320);

            }
            else if (AppMobi.device.model.indexOf("iPad")!=-1)
            {
                AppMobi.display.useViewport(768,768);
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width="768px";
            }
        }

        if (AppMobi.geolocation != null)
        {
            AppMobi.geolocation.watchPosition(suc,fail,options);
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    try
    {
        //lock orientation
        AppMobi.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
        AppMobi.device.setAutoRotate(false);
    }
    catch(e) {}

    try
    {
        //manage power
        AppMobi.device.managePower(true,false);
    }
    catch(e) {}

    try
    {
        //hide splash screen
        AppMobi.device.hideSplashScreen();
    }
    catch(e) {}     
}

//initial event handler to detect when appMobi is ready to roll
document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    function setMarkers() {

 for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var locStatusString = locations[i].split("!",3);
            var loc = locStatusString[0];
            var status = locStatusString[1];
            var user = locStatusString[2];
            if (user !=  AppMobi.cache.getCookie("usernameCookie"))
            {
        var latlngStr= loc.split(",",2);
            var lat = latlngStr[0];
            var lng = latlngStr[1];

var markerLatLng  = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var curicon;

            if (status == "green")
            {   
                curIcon = "greenicon.png";
            }
            else if (status == "yellow")
            {
                curIcon = "yellowicon.png";
            }
            else if (status == "red")
            {
                curIcon = "redicon.png";
            }

                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
'images/marker.png',
new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(16,32)
);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerLatLng,
        map: _map,
        icon: curIcon
    });

    }
}
 }

});

</script>

</head>


<body>
    <div id="afui" class='ios'>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content" style="">

<div class="panel" title="Give A Ride" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_3" style="" data-appbuilder-object="page">
<button onclick = "drawMap()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<div id="map_canvas" style="top: 20%;position:absolute; width:100%;height:80%;text- align:center;"></div>
</div>

            </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also sorry for the formatting this whole 4 space thing screwed up more than it already was.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: The only error is the "drawMap() is undefined" when that button is clicked. If the button isnt clicked everything goes fine including the drawMap() function as called from the ondeviceready();.

Also if I just stick a "alert("hi");" in the onclick it fires so its nothing wrong with the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
url: "http://localhost/getloc.php";
```

And

```
 url = "http://localhost/pickmeup.php";
```

In phonegap app you cannot connect to localhost directly to access above  urls either host them on remote server or use ur computer ip instead of localhost. It should be

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.123/pickmeup.php";     or url="http://someserver.com/pickmeup.php";
```

And also check if u have allowed access to jquery in config.xml

Comment: Yah I fixed the localhost problemm sometime after posting the question, this code is still very much a work in progress it wasnt meant to be accessed remotely anytime soon. And yes the jquery is working fine, just not after button click.